# Angular2 : How to get google place's photos from place id?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-google-maps

I want to retrive google place photos from place id in my angular2 application. I'm getting placeId from Autocomplete method.

> I'm using angular2-google-map library.

```
import { Component, NgZone, Inject, OnInit, ViewChild, EventEmitter, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AgmCoreModule, MapsAPILoader } from 'angular2-google-maps/core';

declare var google: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'add-location-component',
  templateUrl: './addLocation.component.html'
})
export class AddLocationComponent implements OnInit {

  private googlePlaceId: any;

  @ViewChild("search")
  public searchElementRef: ElementRef;
  public searchControl: FormControl;

  constructor(
    public authService: AuthService,
    private mapsAPILoader: MapsAPILoader,
    @Inject(NgZone) private ngZone: NgZone
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.searchControl = new FormControl();
    this.mapsAPILoader.load().then(() => {
      let autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(this.searchElementRef.nativeElement, {
        types: ["address"]
      });
      autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", () => {
        this.ngZone.run(() => {
          let place = autocomplete.getPlace();
          if (place.geometry === undefined || place.geometry === null) {
            return;
          }
          this.googlePlaceId = place.place_id;
          console.log(this.googlePlaceId);
        });
      });
    });
  }
```

}

By using place_id or lattitude and longitude I want to fetch first 10 photos of that place. I'm stuck here with angular2-google-map.

Can you guys help me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this placeId, you'd use the [PlacesService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference?hl=fr#PlacesService) class. You call the `getDetails` method and in the callback you receive a `PlaceResult` which has a `photos` property (it's an array of [`PhotoPlace`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference?hl=fr#PlacePhoto) on which you call the `getUrl` method to retrieve the displayable picture).

(that implies you have retrieved the Place library as well as the core google maps API library)

```
function RetrievePhotoUrlsFromPlaceId(placeId) {
  /* Instantiate a placesService */
  var placesService = new google.maps.places.PlacesService();

  /* Get place details */
  placesServices.getDetails({
    placeId: placeId
  }, (placeResult, status) => {
    if(status === 'OK') {
      var photos = placeResult.photos;
      var urls = []; // we will store the urls here

      photos.forEach((photo) => {
        urls.push(photo.getUrl({
          maxWidht: 500, // at least set one or the other - mandatory
          maxHeight: undefined
        }));
      });

      /* You have your URLs here !! */
    }
  });
}
```

[edit]

Actually there is much simpler since you use the `Autocomplete` and so you already have a  `PlaceResult`.

```
function RetrievePhotoUrlsFromPlace(place) {

     var photos = place.photos;
     var urls = []; // we will store the urls here

          photos.forEach((photo) => {
            urls.push(photo.getUrl({
              maxWidht: 500, // at least set one or the other - mandatory
              maxHeight: undefined
            }));
          });

          /* You have your URLs here !! */
        }
```

Comment: I tried as per your solution, But getting this error **google.maps.PlacesService is not a constructor**

Comment: you probably don't have the Place library loaded

Comment: Yes I have added     `AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: GOOGLEAPIKEY,
      libraries: [ "places" ]
    })`

Comment: my bad it's `new google.maps.places.PlacesService`, I update my post

Comment: We need to pass `HTMLDivElement Or Map` as params to `PlacesService();` method ? Its giving an error **Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of undefined**

Comment: Ok, see my update, you actually already have a `PlaceResult` (the return of `getPlace()`. So you don't need the step where you instantiate a `PlacesService`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136251/discussion-between-hitesh-balar-and-vallenain).

Comment: How is google.maps.places.PlacesService(); imported?